# GStreamer is not working properly on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, gstreamer, raspbian

I am trying to install the newest version of GStreamer onto Raspberry Pi.

I want to instsall both Gstreamer and Gstreamer-dev.

I want the newest version so probably not apt-get install?

The problem I want to solve is that, I do not have element 'faac' or 'avenc_aac', which I need for audio capture.

And also,

```
gst-device-monitor-1.0
```

shows

```
Probing devices...
** (gst-device-monitor-1.0:5760): ERROR **: Failed to start device monitor!
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Which I expect it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't know how to cross compile I suggest you stick to the official release on the Pi. For AAC encoding check the `voaacenc` element which is the recommended AAC encoder for gstreamer currently.

Comment: @Florian Zwoch I have worked out something, which is:   raspivid -t 0 -h 720 -w 1280 -fps 60 -hf -b 2000000 -o - | timeout -s INT 20 gst-launch-1.0 -v fdsrc ! video/x-h264,width=1280,height=720,framerate=60/1 ! h264parse ! queue ! qtmux0. alsasrc device=hw:1,0 ! audioconvert ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! queue ! qtmux0. qtmux ! filesink location=/mnt/ramdisk/sample.mp4 , however, it is still not working..... is there any tips for it?

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? Anyway when dealing with MP4 files you want to add the `-e` flag to `gst-launch-1.0`. This will write correct headers to the MP4 file when you Ctrl-C `gst-lanuch-1.0` execution. If you don't do this the file cannot be played.